# Update unsigned android apk in play store

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore, app-update

We have an app published on play store and the developer has given us the **unsigned** app. How do we proceed in updating the existing app without it being signed?
Is it possible to update an existing app with an unsigned apk after we sign it?

Comment: What did you not understand from "Update your apps" topic on Google's support page? There is a *checklist to make sure your new APK is ready to update*

Comment: those are signed apps unlike mine which is unsigned.

Comment: Basic logic: *The updated APK needs to be signed with the same signature as the current version* <= this is excluding unsigned apps from updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to publish unsigned APK on Google Play.

Ask from your developer for

1) source code,
2) KeyStor file[.jks file]
3) Keystore password,
4) keyAliase password
5) Generate new signed APK using keyStore file provided by your developer 
6) after generating new signed APK, you can update your existing google play application by new APK.

Comment: The app has been transferred to our play store account so i think it is possible to change keystore password ourselves, right?

Comment: but your old Keystore file[provided by your developer] will ask for the old password during signed APK generation, And you have to generate your APK by using old Keystore file for updating existing application on Google play store.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload to Google Store a not signed and not aligend APK. Ask your developer to give you the signed and aligend APK. Or you can ask them to provide the `key` to you so you can sign and align it yourself using that `key`.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.html